# Keycloak for backend service

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

We have some APIs that we'd like to allow a specific backend service we'd like Keycloak to work with. We have it working with regular users with the traditional username/password type login. As you can imagine, we don't want to have a password based system, but ideally some sort of long key we can weld into the calling app to start the authentication process. If it helps to know, I'd like this to be a stateless JWT solution (eventually anyway). Yes, I've seen the documentation, but I don't know where this is talked about. Can someone send me a good link.

Answer (score 1):

**Client Credentials Flow** in OAuth 2.0 for backend service.

#### This is good overview of OAuth Flow

[Diagrams And Movies Of All The OAuth 2.0 Flows](https://darutk.medium.com/diagrams-and-movies-of-all-the-oauth-2-0-flows-194f3c3ade85)

[image]

#### How to call Client Credentials  in Keycloak

[What is a PAT and how to obtain it](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_permission_create_resource)

API format

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}' \
    "http://localhost:8080/realms/${realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

[Keycloak: Client Credentials Grant Example](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-client-credentials-grant-example/)

[Keycloak Realm VS Keycloak Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561554/keycloak-realm-vs-keycloak-client)